# Route all urls to the same file

Tags: .net, url-routing

How do I use Global.asax so one route is listening to ALL urls and mapping it to one file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application_AuthenticateRequest` to transfer all request to single page

Comment: Thanks! But how exactly do I use Application_AuthenticateRequest to do this?